# Not able to click on elements in loop in protractor

Tags: loops, dictionary, filter, protractor

I have a ecommerce website, which has list of products similar to amazon. i am trying to look for a element and click it. i have tried by filter and map and both not working for me. Please help.

Below is the code for each product:

```html
<b class="productNameHover pcursor word-break">product1</b>
<b class="productNameHover pcursor word-break">product2</b>
<b class="productNameHover pcursor word-break">product3</b>
<b class="productNameHover pcursor word-break">product4</b>
```

say i have 4 elements in my page. so, i have tried to get the count and it working for me.

var products = element.all(by.className('productNameHover')) ;
expect(products.count()).toBe(4);

when i tried filter,

**Solution A)** not working, no error message but did nothing

```
var products = element.all(by.className('productNameHover'));

products.filter(function(elem) {
    return products.getText().then(function(text) {
        return text === 'product4';
    });
}).click();

browser.sleep(5000);
```

**Solution B)** not working; index out of bound; Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator

```
var products = element.all(by.className('productNameHover'));

products.filter(function(elem) {
    return products.getText().then(function(text) {
        return text === 'product4';
    });
}).first().click();

browser.sleep(5000);
```

**Soluction C)** no error message but did nothing

```
var products = element.all(by.className('productNameHover'));

products.filter(function(elem) {
    return products
            .element(by.xpath(
                "//div[@class='item text-center slide-image-content active']/img"
            ))
            .getText()
            .then(function(text) {
                expect(text).toContain(product4);
             })
            .then(function(filteredElements) {
                filteredElements.first().click();
            });
});

browser.sleep(5000);
```

**Solution D)** This is working and giving me all the products; but i need to either click on a single product or loop through

```
var products = element.all(by.className('productNameHover'));

products.map(function(item) {
    return item.getText();
}).then(function(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
    //expect(txt).toContain("product 4")
});
```

**Solution E)** not working and no error message

```
products.map(function(item) {
    return item.getText();
}).then(function(txt) {
    console.log(txt);
    if( txt== 'product4') {
        console.log(item);
        item.click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    }
});
```

**Solution F)** I tried to click on all the elements in loop but it is clicking on the first element and not clicking on the second one; it is giving Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

```
products.map(function(item) {
    browser.sleep(5000);
    item.click();
    browser.sleep(5000);
    var backButton = element.all(by.className('btn btn-outline btn-big mt-3 ml-0 ml-sm-2')).first() ;
    backButton.click();
    browser.sleep(5000);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong understand the Protractor API: `each() / map() / filter()`. Recommend you to learn JavaScript Array's [forEach() / map() / filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to have a better understanding before you use Protractor API.

**Solution A)**

1. `return products.getText()` should be `return elem.getText()`.
2. `filter()` return an element array, thus you can't call `click()` on array.

**Solution B)**

1. `return products.getText()` should be `return elem.getText()`.

**Solution E)**  `map()` return array too.

```
products.map(function(item) {
    return item.getText();
}).then(function(txt) {
    // txt = [ 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4']
    console.log(txt);

    if( txt == 'product4') { // this condition never be true
        console.log(item);
        item.click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    }
});

// correct code example
products.map(function(item) {
    return item.getText();
}).then(function(txts) {
    // txts = [ 'product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4']
    console.log(txts);

    let index = txts.indexOf('product4');

    if( index > -1) {
        products.get(index).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of solution E. Now, it give better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [each()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) function of the protractor API ?

```
 var products = element.all(by.className('productNameHover'));
 products.each(function(element) {
   return element.getText().then(function (text) {
           if(text === 'product4') {
               return element.click();
           }
    });
 })
```

I would suggest you to switch to new `async/await` syntax of writing js code.

```
 const products = element.all(by.className('productNameHover'));
 products.each(async function(element) {
    let text = await element.getText();
           if(text === 'product4') {
               await element.click();
           }
 });
```

You can also use `map()` function -

```
element.all(by.className('productNameHover')).map(function(element) {
         return element.getText(function(text) {
                 return text === 'product4'
           });
     }).then(function(elements) {
           for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                  elements.get(i).click();
             }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you got it working and I may be misunderstanding, but if you're just trying to click on a specific product in the list, you can use

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.productNameHover', 'product4')).click();
```